# How to convert Mysqli results into an array in OO Php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, oop, mysqli

I want to retrieve data from a table in database and display the result in an array in the form below.

array("1"=>"Value 1", "2"=>"value2")
Here is the function I tried using but I get error when I try to display the array. Please I need help on this. I'm new to OO Php.

```
<?php
class query {

public function listfields (){
    $result = $this->mysqli->query("SELECT id, name FROM fields", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);
    while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
    $this->fields[$row["id"]] = $row["name"];
    }
    $result->free();

}

public function fields(){
return $this->fields;   
}
        }


$list = new query;
$list->listfields();
$field1 = $list->fields();

echo $field1;
?>
```

Comment: Posting the error you are getting is often quite useful.

Comment: @muhammad-zeeshan Thanks for the response. print_r($field1) now returns array in this form: Array ( [1] => Engineering [6] => Physical Sciences [2] => Technology ); Is there a way to convert it to display in this form array("1"=>"Engineering", "6"=>"Physical Sciences")

Comment: what about  [2] => Technology?

Comment: @Muhammad-Zeeshan sorry it would be included too array("1"=>"Engineering", "6"=>"Physical Sciences", "2"=>"Technology")

Comment: @andychukse: It is already an array, what do you mean by convert?

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshan Sorry that was an error, I got it now thanks a million

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
<?php

class query {

public function listfields (){

 $fields = array();
 $rowcnt =1;
 $result = $this->mysqli->query("SELECT id, name FROM fields", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);
    while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
      $this->fields[$row["id"]] = $row["name"];
     //$this->fields[$rowcnt] = $row["name"];   // if you want different indexing.
      $rowcnt++;
 }
 $result->free();
}

public function fields(){
    return $this->fields;   
}
}
$list = new query();
$list->listfields();
$field1 = $list->fields();
var_dump($field1);
?>
```

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshan I made changes. I went in javascript+php mode. :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your function fields, you will need a property fields, which you can access.
Furthermore i suggest using getters and setters instead of a public property, im sure you will find out how.

This will return the Data in form array("1"=>"Value 1", "2"=>"value2").

```
class query {

public $fields;

public function fillfields ()
{
    $result = $this->mysqli->query("SELECT id, name FROM fields", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);
    while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
         $this->fields[] = $row["name"];
    }
    $result->free();
}

$list = new query;
$list->fillfields();
$field1 = $list->fields[1];

echo $field1;
```